# Solving a non-linear boundary value problem (NDSolve) for a small non-linearity

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{a}{b}y-\frac{u}{b}y^3=0,\quad \frac{dy}{dx}\Big\vert_{x=0}+\frac{s}{b}y\vert_{x=0}=0,\quad \frac{dy}{dx}\Big\vert_{x=L}-\frac{s}{b}y\vert_{x=L}=0.$$ For $u=0$, and $L\to\infty$, the homogeneous system allows a non-trivial solution only for $a=\frac{s^2}{b}$. Furthermore, this critical value of $a$ increases with decreasing $L$. I am trying to solve the non-linear problem with $u\neq 0$, while allowing an extrapolation to the limit $u\to 0$. I am expecting that a solution would show up for $a\lessapprox \frac{s^2}{b}$, which is what I am trying to see explicitly.

This script does not seem to be working. Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
{b, s, u, L, a} = {0.05, 0.1, 0.0001, 100, 0.1}; sol = 
 NDSolve[{y''[x] - (a/b)*y[x] - (u/b)*(y[x])^3 == 0, 
   y'[0] + (s/b)*y[0] == 0, y'[L] - (s/b)*y[L] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, L}];
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: This problem has trivial solution $y=0$. To avoid zero solution we need to add some normalization condition like `Integrate[y[x]^2, {x,0,L}]=1`.

Comment: For y'[0]=y'[L]=0 (Neumann conditions), i.e., with $s=0$, the solution is simply $\sqrt{a/u}$, making the unit normalization not a good way. For a the states boundary conditions with $s\neq 0$, this makes the normalization non-trivial. Nonetheless, some way is needed, as you stated, to discard the trivial solution.

Comment: What constraints are placed on the parameters?  For instance, are they all positive.?